# What's the best way to handle function calls and data transfer between Servlet and HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, xml, servlets

I'm developing Web application using Servlet. Right now I'm able to display data retrieved from MySQL database and display it to HTML; even user logging in works and response is shown on HTML via Servlet.

Specifically in case of Withdrawal transaction of bank account, there is need of multiple call transfer and data handling between Servlet and HTML. I've tried using XML for data transfer, and it works for single call with static data. But I'm unable to optimize it for withdrawal process.

Can you please tell me better way of doing this?

Comment: Need to be far more specific

Answer (score 1):

to develop web application in servlets,its always better to use MVC pattern(architecture) which separates code into 3 different groups

1)Model - this part of the framework is to store the data of the application, such as databases, text data, files and/or other web resources.

2)View - this is the graphical user interface of the application. That would contain different buttons, text boxes and other controls to let the user interact with the application to complete his projects depending on sort of the software he is using.(jsps,html pages)

3)Controller - the actual back-end code constitutes the controller of the framework. A controller controls the data coming from the users, or going to the user from a model(servlet code)

advantage of MVC pattern are
1)code reuse
2)separating of concerns
3)less coupling between the layers